# Django: How to display the profile pic of particular user who have written the question?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

This is my profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Full_Name = models.CharField(max_length=32,blank=True)
    Name = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    E_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='user_images', null=True, blank=True)
```

This is my Question model:

```
class Consultancy(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Questions = models.TextField()
```

I tried using this in my template:

```
            {% if consultancy.User.profile.image %}
                <img class="img-circle img-sm" src="{{ consultancy.User.user.profile.image.url }}/" alt="">
            {% else %}
                <img class="img-circle img-sm" src="{% static 'userprofile/download (1).jpg' %}">
            {% endif %}
```

But this doesn't worked...

I am creating a simple consultancy application...I want to display the profile picture of the users who have written the question..

What do I have to do in my template to make this possible..

Any idea anyone???

Comment: What does your template have so far?

Comment: I have updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `user` references in your image src. It should just be:

```
<img class="img-circle img-sm" src="{{ consultancy.User.profile.image.url }}">
```